# How to skip a character and move the cursor to the next position in an input using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, user-input

Hi how to skip a character and move the cursor to the next position in a string? For instance within the input string `123-4-789`, when I insert `5` in between `4` and `-` it should become `123-45-789` and the cursor should be between `-` and `7` instead of `5` and `-`. So if `6` is inserted now string should become `123-45-6789`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look at the [A-Tools plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/a-tools) for jQuery.

Basic usage appears to be:

```
var cSelection = $("#myInput").getSelection();

/* might give, (start and end would be equal for normal caret operation) */
cSelection = { 'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'text': '123', 'length': 3 };

/* move caret to one place after end of selection */
$('#myInput').setCaretPos(cSelection.end + 1);
```